# Trigger that checks if multiple values are equal over two tables and then updates table

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have a situation where I'm trying to create a trigger that as soon as I manually update a specific row in table1 regarding the game number, I'd like it to compare/evaluate the changes that have been updated in table1(liveResult) towards the existing values from table2(prediction) and then if these values are correct it needs to update all rows regarding that game number in table2(predictionCorrect) to value "1" else value "0".

I'm not a guru with MySQL and I keep getting the below error and I cannot pinpoint what the problem is, sure it might be something simple but unfortunately I'm unable to spot it...

I have tried a few sites that show how to do something similar but at this point I keep getting the following error:

"1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9"

I'm unfortunately not a MySQL guru and have never created triggers before so I appoligize should this be something simple...

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_update_tableCorrect
AFTER UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF (liveResult = (Select prediction from table2 where gameNr = '5')) 
THEN
    UPDATE table2
    SET predictionCorrect = '1'
    where gameNr = '5';
ELSE
    UPDATE table2
    SET predictionCorrect = '0'
    where gameNr = '5';
END IF;
END;
```

What I'm looking to do is like the example below:

```
Table 1:
gameNr | liveResult
  5    |     10

Table 2:
gameNr | prediction | predictionCorrect
  5    |     10     |         1 // Prediction correct!
  5    |     15     |         0 // Prediction wrong!
  5    |     10     |         1 // Prediction correct!
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check the syntax use old, new kind of approach, btw i think the error is due to you haven't used delimiter before starting the trigger.

Comment: @James Will look into the use of old.. Let me try the delimeter, forgot to add it.. ai...

Comment: @James Okay so the delimeter helped save the trigger so it's in place, so I know tried changing the LiveResult but it doesn't seem to update the predictionCorrect from table 2... Will look into this a bit, you happy that the if statement regarding the evaluation is correct?

Comment: Nope, there are issues. Trigger works based on each row and your if liveresult=value so what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the guidance @James. It would seem that the reason it's not updating is because although I'm referencing table 1, using liveResult in the IF statement doesn't seem to be recognized so I added another select in there that looks as follows:

```
IF ((Select prediction from table1 where gameNr = '5') = (Select liveResult from table2 where gameNr = '5'))
```

Know it's no ideal but this seemed to have done the trick and atleast the tables are now updating accordingly. Will still look into the Old approach.

Thanks.